# Insert node with the text of the clicked label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, e-commerce

I have this section of code for an eCommerce.

```js
function appendChildElement() {
    var labelOptionSelected = $("#filters fieldset label");
    labelOptionSelected.each(function() {
      labelOptionSelected.click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          if ($(labelOptionSelected).hasClass('sr_selected')) {
            const text = $('.sr_selected').text();
            const insertNode = document.querySelector(".fg-container--filterSelected");
                  insertNode.innerHTML = "<a href='#' onclick='' class='fg-container--filterSelected-option'>" + text + " x</a>";
          }
        }, 500);
      });
    });
  }
  appendChildElement();
```

What I require is that each `<label>` clicked, copy the text of said `<label>` and insert it in a specific link.

That means that if I click on the `<label 1>`, copy the text of this `<label>` and create a link with the text and if I click on the `<label 2>` copy the text of this `< label>` and put it in another additional link.

I put the example of the code as it is currently working

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Here the links of the clicked labels would be created -->
    <a href='#' onclick='removeThisFilter()' class='fg-container--filterSelected-option'>Clicked label 1Clicked label 2Clicked label 3Clicked label 4</a>
<div>
<fieldset>
    <label class="00001" title="00001" index="0">Category Name 1</label>
    <label class="00002" title="00002" index="1">Category Name 2</label>
    <label class="00003" title="00003" index="2">Category Name 3</label>
    <label class="00004" title="00004" index="3">Category Name 4</label>
</fieldset>
```

Currently the code works but not correctly, if I click on label 1, it adds the link with the text, but if I additionally click on label 2, it adds the text but within the same initial link. And what is required to be in a separate link within the same `<div>` resulting in something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href='#' onclick='removeThisFilter()' class='fg-container--filterSelected-option'>Clicked label 1</a>
    <a href='#' onclick='removeThisFilter()' class='fg-container--filterSelected-option'>Clicked label 2</a>
    <a href='#' onclick='removeThisFilter()' class='fg-container--filterSelected-option'>Clicked label 3</a>
<div>
<fieldset>
    <label class="00001" title="00001" index="0">Category Name 1</label>
    <label class="00002" title="00002" index="1">Category Name 2</label>
    <label class="00003" title="00003" index="2">Category Name 3</label>
    <label class="00004" title="00004" index="3">Category Name 4</label>
</fieldset>
```

The functionality is basically for a category filter in the PDP of a page.

Annex mockup of what they request, maybe and they will understand me better with the image

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSoK2.png)

Tell me that you can help me please, I have looked in several parts but I can not find the solution.

Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I decided to use the Jquery option, since it also adds a `data-text` to the link which allows me to issue a script below to deactivate that filter from the selection of filters on the localhost. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure if this was what you were after, but I simplified your code, made it so you can't add the same link twice and added a way for you to remove the links as well. Also, since you tagged this as jquery, I made it all jquery

```js
$("#filters fieldset label").click(function() {
  let t = $(this).text().trim();
  let newlink = `<a href='#' onclick='removeMe(this)' class='fg-container--filterSelected-option' data-val="${t}">${t}</a>`;
  let exists = $(`.container a[data-val="${t}"]`).length > 0;
  if (!exists) $('.container').append(newlink)
});

function removeMe(el) {
  $(el).remove();
}
```

```css
.container a,
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='filters'>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Here the links of the clicked labels would be created -->
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <label class="00001" title="00001" index="0">Category Name 1</label>
        <label class="00002" title="00002" index="1">Category Name 2</label>
        <label class="00003" title="00003" index="2">Category Name 3</label>
        <label class="00004" title="00004" index="3">Category Name 4</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello Kinglish, the truth is spectacular with your solution, with respect to Jquery there is no mess, since the CMS allows to use Jquery or Vanilla Javascript, with respect to the "Delete" function I cannot take it, since it must fulfill other 3 functions for below, but the rest is perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't need to each `<label>` tag.

You can add click event by the way:

```
<script>
    const insertNode = $('.container')
    const filters = $('#filters')

    $('#filters fieldset label').click(function (e) {
        const text = $(this).text();

        // Check if a tag with the content TEXT has been added before or not
        // You can see detail find() function in here: https://api.jquery.com/find/
        // This is my way to check duplicate labels, you can consider another way
        const isAdded = insertNode.find('a[data-text="'+ text +'"]');
        if (isAdded.length === 0) {
            const html = "<a href='#' data-text='"+ text +"' onclick='' class='fg-container--filterSelected-option'>" + text + " x</a>"
            insertNode.append(html)
        }
    })
</script>
```

When clicking on `<label>`. The div tag looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" data-text="Category Name 1" onclick="" class="fg-container--filterSelected-option">Category Name 1 x</a>
    <a href="#" data-text="Category Name 2" onclick="" class="fg-container--filterSelected-option">Category Name 2 x</a>
    <a href="#" data-text="Category Name 3" onclick="" class="fg-container--filterSelected-option">Category Name 3 x</a>
</div>
```

How to remove them, when you click on them. Follow your way, add `onclick` to each `<a>`:

> `<a href='#' onclick='removeThisFilter()'> </a>`

Or try this way:

```
// event handle remove tag
insertNode.delegate('a', 'click', function () {
    $(this).remove();
})
```

Comment: Hello Lam Tran Duc, the truth is, your Script also worked, with respect to the Labels, if they are necessary, because the Labels are already built from the CMS, that is why the use of the Label was mandatory. Thanks a lot